# Does the KnockoutJS observableArray do a diff between old and new array before notifying subscribers?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using KnockoutJS library and I can't figure out one thing: does the KnockoutJS notify the subscribers of the `observableArray` if it was updated with different array that contains exact same values (for example the copy of the old array)?

Comment: Why don't you try it out, or write a unit test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that it does not check the array in any way before notifying subscribers. Knockout includes a utility function, `ko.utils.compareArrays`, that compares two arrays and returns the differences. It's used internally by `ko.utils.setDomNodeChildrenFromArrayMapping`, which is in turn used by the `foreach` binding.